# Создание процесса в линукс с path=NULL: kill(pid, 0) == 0 хотя процесс уже вышел _exit()

Tags: c++, linux, multiprocessing, poco

Нужно запустить процесс и в родительском процессе проверить запустился ли он.
Я хочу сделать это с помощью библиотеки POCO примерно так:

```
poco::ProcessHandle handle = poco::Process::launch(path, arg, workingDirectory);
if ( !poco::Process::isRunning(handle) )
{
   ...
}
```

Внутри все работает следующим образом: вызывается `fork()` запоминается pid. В дочернем процессе вызывается `execvp()` и далее вызывается `_exit()`;

Внутри `isRunning()` вызывается `kill(pid, 0)`.

Все это работает, вопрос возникает когда переменная `path` равна нулю, то есть никакой другой исполняемый файл выполнятся не должен. 
Но почему то `kill(pid, 0)` возвращает 0, то есть процесс запущен, как такое может быть?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0)
    {
        int pid = getpid();
        int ppid = getppid();

        printf("Child process: pid: %d \n", pid);
        printf("Child process: ppid: %d \n", ppid);
        int res = execvp("", NULL);
        printf("Child process: res: %d \n", res);
        _exit(72);
    }
    sleep(3);

    if ( kill(pid, 0) == 0 )
    {
        printf("kill returned 0 \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Child process: pid: 3542 
Child process: ppid: 3533 
Child process: res: -1 
kill returned 0
```

Вывод `ps -ef | grep 3533`

```
milai      3533   3531  0 15:55 pts/6    00:00:00 /home/milai/project/test/build/testApp
milai      3542   3533  0 15:55 pts/6    00:00:00 [testApp] <defunct>
milai      3561   2579  0 15:57 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 3533
```

Comment: Я пробовал ставить sleep в пять секунд после запуска процесса, но это не помогло

Comment: grep я сделал чтобы весь вывод не писать. Я правильно понимаю что дочерний процесс считается запущенным поскольку он не вернул код завершения?  А как же `_exit()`? Если `waitpid` не вызывать то созданный процесс так и будет висеть?

Как тогда можно отследить запустился ли процесс(исполняемый файл) успешно или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`kill(pid, 0)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) можно [использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186516/4279), чтобы проверить есть ли процесс с pid в текущей таблице процессов. Когда `_exit(72)` происходит, то процесс завершается, но запись с соответствующим pid всё ещё остаётся в таблице, [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/0b0a14fd8b436a04071d55e9b6f53bf4):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Show that `kill(pid, 0)` is successful for zombies (no ESRCH)."""
from os import *

pid = fork()
if pid == 0:  # child process
    _exit(42)

# parent process
# wait until the child dies (becomes zombie)
while system(fr"ps -ef | grep {pid} | grep defunct\> >{devnull}"):
    pass

kill(pid, 0)  # no exception: zombie "exists"

w_pid, status = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)  # reap zombie
assert w_pid == pid and WIFEXITED(status)
assert WEXITSTATUS(status) == 42, status
try:
    kill(pid, 0)
except ProcessLookupError:  # errno.ESRCH
    pass
else:
    assert 0, "can't be"
```

pid будет занят, пока родитель не вызовет [`wait()` или аналог](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html#tag_16_645), дочерний процесс остаётся [*зомби*](https://askubuntu.com/a/427222/3712) — если родитель выйдет, не вызвав `wait()`, то другой процесс станет родителем (как правило init-процесс с `pid == 1`), который вызовет `wait()` в конечном счёте.

Подобное поведение `poco::Process::isRunning()` не уникально, к примеру, [`psutil.Process.is_running()` явно задокументирован на поддержку zombie](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#psutil.Process.is_running). Хотя есть люди, которые считают это поведение неправильным и оно может измениться: [Poco::Process::isRunning always returning true while process has been tagged defunct](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1097).